# What is the CSS for Firefox's URL suggestion popup?

Tags: css, user-interface, firefox, customization, xul

I wasn't able to find the popup with suggestions of URLs when you begin typing an address. Just to be clear – here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: Firefox suggestion popup]

I'm using the [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+I) to figure out the CSS. Even with the "automate hiding popups" disabled, the suggestion popup still disappears. No chance to pick any element in that box.

I'm just trying to alter the size of some text, so I don't want to install any additional plugins for such a simple task.

Comment: Your browser is no website, it's an application on your computer. No CSS used there.

Comment: nope, i wouldn't say this... look at http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes ;)

Comment: @D.Simon Well, technically, there could still be CSS used there. It could even be modified in a file somewhere on the hard drive. Still nothing you could access with the dev tools, of course.

Comment: @Xufox of course there IS the dev tool for this. why would i bother to ask? if you didn't try, just go to dev tool settings-advanced and check "..tool for chrome and addons" and "remote tracking". than you can access this by the shortcut i've posted in my question

Comment: @Xufox added the link for this to a question for you

Comment: @D. Simon: Firefox's UI is rendered almost entirely using XUL and CSS.

Comment: @Xufox, the XUL, CSS and JavaScript which are used for the majority of Firefox's UI have been modifiable by extensions for a very long time. It's a significant part of what makes (almost made (past tense), as the capability is going away) Firefox extensions *vastly* more capable than Chrome extensions. You can also add a *chrome/userChrome.css* file in your profile directory which will apply CSS rules to the browser UI.

Comment: Related: [Firefox how to get dark themed searchbar-results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41623765)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID of that popup is `#PopupAutoCompleteRichResult`. Unfortunately, for some reason it doesn't respect the setting that disables autohiding of popups.

The good news is that you should be able to locate it in the browser chrome even when it's hidden by dropping that selector into the search field in the Inspector in the Browser Toolbox. You can also navigate to it manually by looking in `window#main-window > popupset#mainPopupSet`.

The text in each item can be styled using the selectors `.ac-title` and `.ac-url`. These elements are also referenced in chrome://browser/skin/browser.css.

Comment: THAT'S IT man :) finally i tracked to a `window#main-window popupset#mainPopupSet panel#PopupAutoCompleteRichResult` thanks a lot